# Mysql condition becoming string after adding variable

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

Mysql condition becoming string after adding `$city` OR `$findname` variable
As I ad ("") '".$city."' rest of part becoming invalid

```
$findname = $_POST['findname'];
                                    
$city = $_POST['city'];
                                            
$show_details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * from directory WHERE city LIKE '".$city."' OR findname LIKE '".$findname."'");
    
foreach ($show_details as $k => $v) {
   
    echo $v->name . "<br />";
}
```

Comment: *Please see the editor image* Do this: `sql1 = {query with variables and substitution}; sql2 = {query with literals};` then check that `sql1` == `sql2`.

Comment: Make sure yor are getting value in $_POST

Comment: @Akina would write those 2 lines for me here!

Comment: @Mahmodul Try to add string variables without double quotes and `.` around it

Comment: `$wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * from directory WHERE city LIKE '$city' OR findname LIKE '$findname'");`

Comment: @groovy_guy I did, but '$city' variable  becoming string ..

Comment: so, @Mahmodul is your `$city` variable an integer? if it is remove the single quotes as well.
In case if your query is something else it'd be a help for users to understand if you can update your question with the error you are receiving.

Comment: @groovy_guy $city = $_POST['city']; here $city receiving value well eg: Chicago,  As I ad ("") '".$city."' rest of part becoming invalid,

Comment: Try to use parentheses: `LIKE '".($city)."'`.

Comment: @Robert I did it very first its only works for single argument $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE city LIKE '".($city)."'");  But when I ad next next part: OR findname LIKE $findname '".$findname."'"); same way it not works

Comment: So I think it's time for you to consider using prepare statements instead, as your query is sql injection vulnerable.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
$show_details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE city LIKE '",$city,"' OR findname LIKE '",$findname,"'");
```

Comment: As I ad ("") '",$city,"' rest of part becoming invalid .. returning NULL

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can test whether your assumptions are correct, via:

```
$show_details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * from directory WHERE city LIKE 'Chicago' OR findname LIKE 'John Doe'");
```

This should be syntactically correct. So, since your query fails, it is highly probable that you have an issue with the value itself, like the **Chicago** you have might be enclosed by single quotes, like `'Chicago'`. That would result in something of the like of

```
$show_details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * from directory WHERE city LIKE ''Chicago'' OR findname LIKE 'John Doe'");
```

which is NOT syntactically correct. Seeing this it become clear that single quotes need to properly handled, that is, your program needs to reliably differentiate the single quotes you use to encapsulate your textual information from the single quotes that can be part of the data.

In our case, single-quote-issues are manifesting themselves in some fixable bug. But what if a malicious programmer would find out that your code does not properly differentiate the single quotes you wrap around textual data from single quotes that are part of the data? They could intentionally add single-quotes to the search terms or other data to end your search command and they would also add a new command of malicious code. For example, your data could be `Chicago'; delete from directory;`. That appended as the value of `$city` will result in

```
$show_details = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT  * from directory WHERE city LIKE '`Chicago'; delete from directory`;' OR findname LIKE 'John Doe'");
```

It would then run some search command, remove directories from your database and then run some invalid command that the hacker would not care about. This is a serious danger called [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp).

You can add [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) to your code, so your query would look like

```
"SELECT * FROM directory WHERE city LIKE ? OR findname LIKE ?"
```

and PDO would handle the quote escaping for you. Since you almost certainly have quotes wrapped around your Chicago search term, your query will likely not find the records you want, but it will be syntactically correct. In order to fix the other issue that you have, you will need to make sure that whatever initializes the value of city will not artificially wrap quotes around it.